# /execute and /testfor commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a map with some commands, one being when the player gets within ten blocks of a command block, a door is revealed or a boss is summoned. I couldn't figure out how to do it. Can someone please help? Thanks. I might have figured out the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is =! not working in testfor command?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/285213/why-is-not-working-in-testfor-command)

Comment: no it is not5 a duplicate mine is completely different

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate. but, @Geoplayer123, please mark the answer below as accepted if it helped you figure out the problem.

Comment: The answer lies within... no jk but the answer is in the "this duplicate" post

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in one command block:

```
/testfor @e[r=10,type=Player]
```

Put a comparator next to it with the input side facing the comparator, and then you have to trigger that command block all the time.

When there is a player within a radius of 10 (10 from each side) the comparator gets activated. Then you can make that redstone signal do anything.

Comment: You don't have to use a comparator anymore, as they take a redstone tick to activate. If you want everything to be done at the same time, consider using chain conditional command blocks, where they will only activate if the chain command block before them has been successful with its command (ie, if it would produce a comparator signal).

Comment: no it doesnt work.

Comment: You need to activate it all the time. You can now set the command block to be **Always Active** or use any clock.